# Why won't my mysqli insert/update work

Tags: php, mysqli, insert-update

What is wrong with my coding, since it won't work?

```
$empsql("SELECT * FROM employees WHERE e_id ='$ed_id' ");

if($rows > 0)  {
    $empsql('UPDATE employees SET name = "'.$name.'" , description = "'.$description.'" , telephone = "'.$telephone.'" , email = "'.$email.'" WHERE e_id = "'.$ed_id.'" ');
}
else
{
    $empsql("INSERT INTO employees (name,description,telephone,email) VALUES ('$name','$description','$telephone','$email') ");
}
```

Comment: What is `$empsql()`? It has the name of a variable but you're using it as a function. Aren't you seeing syntax errors? Look in your server error log

Comment: i don't get any errors, lonely a blank/empty page..
I'm not so good to php,
so how do I make it right?

Comment: Don't forget to paste the error message or unexpected behavior you get with your question, as we find "it won't work" unhelpful.

Answer (score 0):

You should really stick to the basics, because your syntax makes no sense. This code makes more sense.

```
$empsql = "SELECT * FROM employees WHERE e_id ='$ed_id'";
$rows = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($empsql));

if(!empty($rows))  {
    mysql_query('UPDATE employees SET name = "'.$name.'" , description = "'.$description.'" , telephone = "'.$telephone.'" , email = "'.$email.'" WHERE e_id = "'.$ed_id.'" ');
}
else
{
    mysql_query("REPLACE INTO employees (name,description,telephone,email) VALUES ('$name','$description','$telephone','$email') ");
}
```

Comment: How about combining the two queries with REPLACE INTO?

Comment: Same syntax as the INSERT, but replace INSERT with REPLACE. That said, your data (the VALUES) have to include the KEY value so that SQL can determine whether this is a duplicate record (do an UPDATE) or whether it doesn't exist (do an INSERT). Do you have a KEY, such as maybe the e_id?